# Create/Recreate Azure CosmosDb async client from Java reactor context

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, spring-webflux

Due to company's policy, our CosmosDb keys are rotated periodically with the new keys in Azure KeyVault so we need to deal with this changing key in our Java weblfux/reactive application. From Java SDK, once a CosmosAsyncClient is created from master key there is no way to change it and we need to rebuild it with roughly the following code:

```java
SecretAsyncClient secretAsyncClient = new SecretClientBuilder().buildAsyncClient()
...
Mono<CosmosAsyncClient> client = secretAsyncClient.getSecret(KEY_NAME).map(
  s -> s.getValue()
).map(
  key -> new CosmosClientBuilder()
                        .endpoint(HOST)
                        .key(key)
                        .buildAsyncClient()
);
return client.flatMap(
   ...
);
```

From the log, the `getSecret()` is OK but then I got:

```
05:25:00.597 INFO  c.a.c.i.RxDocumentClientImpl - Initializing DocumentClient [4] with serviceEndpoint [https://xxxx-cosmosdb-sql-dev.documents.azure.com:443/], connectionPolicy [ConnectionPolicy{httpNetworkRequestTimeout=PT1M, tcpNetworkRequestTimeout=PT5S, connectionMode=DIRECT, maxConnectionPoolSize=1000, idleHttpConnectionTimeout=PT1M, idleTcpConnectionTimeout=PT0S, userAgentSuffix='', throttlingRetryOptions=RetryOptions{maxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests=9, maxRetryWaitTime=PT30S}, endpointDiscoveryEnabled=true, preferredRegions=[Switzerland North], multipleWriteRegionsEnabled=true, proxyType=null, inetSocketProxyAddress=null, readRequestsFallbackEnabled=true, connectTimeout=PT5S, idleTcpEndpointTimeout=PT1H, maxConnectionsPerEndpoint=130, maxRequestsPerConnection=30, tcpConnectionEndpointRediscoveryEnabled=true}], consistencyLevel [Session], directModeProtocol [Tcp]05:25:00.598 ERROR c.a.c.i.RxDocumentClientImpl - unexpected failure in initializing client.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-epoll-3
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.http.ReactorNettyClient.attemptToWarmupHttpClient(ReactorNettyClient.java:118)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.http.ReactorNettyClient.createWithConnectionProvider(ReactorNettyClient.java:98)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.http.HttpClient.createFixed(HttpClient.java:61)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.httpClient(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:617)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.<init>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:410)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.<init>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:262)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.<init>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:230)
        at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.AsyncDocumentClient$Builder.build(AsyncDocumentClient.java:243)
        at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosAsyncClient.<init>(CosmosAsyncClient.java:129)
        at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(CosmosClientBuilder.java:779)
```

So it seems that I need to put the `CosmosClientBuilder().buildAsyncClient()` part to an executor pool? Is there any simpler or more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a short dig through the source code and the error message is correct. There is a [blocking call](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/1f446ddccb121c13a4e47eeafa794de2a8cabba3/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/implementation/http/ReactorNettyClient.java#L112) in the `CosmosClientAsync`.

The library does something actually pretty ugly, they do a [dynamic lookup](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/1f446ddccb121c13a4e47eeafa794de2a8cabba3/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/implementation/http/ReactorNettyClient.java#L52) on the `warmup` function in the the Netty HttpClient and then invokes this.

The warmup function on the Netty HttpClient ([according to the documentation](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/43169a9db51cdb20d262c1435d02abce3c46edf1/reactor-netty-core/src/main/java/reactor/netty/transport/ClientTransport.java#L358)) does the following:

> Based on the actual configuration, returns a Mono that triggers:
>
> - an initialization of the event loop group
> - an initialization of the host name resolver
> - loads the necessary native libraries for the transport
>
> By default, when method is not used, the connect operation absorbs the extra time needed to initialize and load the resources.

In the cosmos library this warmup call does not seem to be configurable.

I think i would actually open an issue in their github and asking them about this.